# Django. TemplateDoesNotExist in case of a custom widget

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I'm trying to create a custom widget in Django admin. I created a class:

```
class FroalaWYSIWYGTextareaWidget(django.forms.widgets.Textarea):
    template_name = 'froala_wysiwyg.html'
```

Then a simple model form:

```
class ArticleForm(django.forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
        model = Article
        widgets = {
            'content': FroalaWYSIWYGTextareaWidget(),
        }
```

Here are my settings:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_PATH, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'django.template.context_processors.static',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Usualy everything works fine and Django can find templates in my /templates/ directory but in case of this widget I have a 500 Error:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /admin/article/article/1/change/
froala_wysiwyg.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/article/article/1/change/
Django Version: 1.11.4
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value: froala_wysiwyg.html
Exception Location: /home/username/.virtualenvs/sitename/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/engine.py in find_template, line 148
Python Executable:  /home/username/.virtualenvs/sitename/bin/python
Python Version: 3.5.2
```

I debugged django.filesystem.loader and found out that usually Loader.engine.dirs is a list:
`['/home/username/python/sitename/templates']`
so Loader.get_template_sources() works great

but in case of this custom widget this loader.engine.dirs contains only:
`['/home/username/.virtualenvs/sitename/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/templates']`

So it just ignores `DIRS` option from the settings and uses forms/templates instead. Is it a bug of Django or I have to change something in settings?
I don't understand where does this `django/forms/templates` path come from?
Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Its certainly not a bug

> **I don't understand where does this django/forms/templates path come from?**

You can view the [source code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_modules/django/forms/widgets/#Textarea) where you can see the line

```
[docs]class Textarea(Widget):
    template_name = 'django/forms/widgets/textarea.html'
```

This was the source of your first question. Now second one

> This renderer uses a standalone DjangoTemplates engine (unconnected to what you might have configured in the TEMPLATES setting). It loads templates first from the built-in form templates directory in django/forms/templates and then from the installed apps’ templates directories using the app_directories loader.

This is true for your form widget classes also. To make things work for you custom widget template you have to specify the path with same terminology like `app_name/forms/widget/textarea.html`

Comment: Well. 
But what I should to do if I   want change textarea.html for ONE field only ?

Comment: @Viach In that case you can inherit this class and make a new class having a custom textarea.html then you can supply that in your widget parameter in forms

Comment: I tryin this in same context with djago 2.2 not work ! The last answer work !

Answer (score 57):

If you want to use a custom widget template stored somewhere under your "TEMPLATES" directory of your project then follow these steps:

a) Use the `TEMPLATES` settings that you have provided in your question

b) Set the `FORM_RENDERER` as following in the `settings.py`

```
FORM_RENDERER = 'django.forms.renderers.TemplatesSetting'
```

c) Add the app "`django.forms`" to the '`INSTALLED_APPS`' list in `settings.py`

Also, be sure to assign the correct path of the custom widget template relative to your "`TEMPLATES`" directory to "`template_name`" attribute of your custom widget.

Comment: IMHO Best answer

Comment: So weird that it requires this.

Comment: Great response. But Why It not found in django doc ?

Comment: I was missing the "django.forms" in the settings thanks for pointing it out